# UISegmentedController pushes down view

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uiview, uisegmentedcontrol

After each time I press same segment my table view controller is pushed down from view about size of one cell. Any one have Idea why it happens? Other views which don't contain any table views works fine.
Here is image how it looks like[image]

**EDIT :** Code from the comments:

```
- (void)indexDidChangeForSegmentedControl:(UISegmentedControl *)aSegmentedControl {
    NSUInteger index = aSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex;
    UIViewController * incomingViewController = [self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:index];
    NSArray * theViewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:incomingViewController];
    [self.navigationController setViewControllers:theViewControllers animated:NO];
    incomingViewController.navigationItem.titleView = aSegmentedControl;
}

- (void)tableView: (UITableView*)tableView willDisplayCell: (UITableViewCell*)cell forRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    cell.backgroundColor = indexPath.row % 2 ? [UIColor colorWithRed:216.0f/255.0f green:235.0f/255.0f blue:213.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f] : [UIColor colorWithRed:178.0f/255.0f green:107.0f/255.0f blue:146.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"CaviarDreams" size:23];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = indexPath.row % 2 ?[UIColor colorWithRed:178.0f/255.0f green:107.0f/255.0f blue:146.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f] :[UIColor colorWithRed:216.0f/255.0f green:235.0f/255.0f blue:213.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

Comment: There is something going on in the code that initializes the table view, or in its data source. Could you please show the code for the "cell for index path", and the code that you run when you switch segments?

Comment: - (void)indexDidChangeForSegmentedControl:(UISegmentedControl *)aSegmentedControl {
    NSUInteger index = aSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex;
    UIViewController * incomingViewController = [self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:index];
    
    NSArray * theViewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:incomingViewController];
    [self.navigationController setViewControllers:theViewControllers animated:NO];
    
    incomingViewController.navigationItem.titleView = aSegmentedControl;
}

Comment: - (void)tableView: (UITableView*)tableView
  willDisplayCell: (UITableViewCell*)cell 
forRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    cell.backgroundColor = indexPath.row % 2
    ? [UIColor colorWithRed:216.0f/255.0f green:235.0f/255.0f blue:213.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]
    : [UIColor colorWithRed:178.0f/255.0f green:107.0f/255.0f blue:146.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    
 cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"CaviarDreams" size:23];

Comment: cell.textLabel.textColor = indexPath.row % 2
    ?[UIColor colorWithRed:178.0f/255.0f green:107.0f/255.0f blue:146.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]
    :[UIColor colorWithRed:216.0f/255.0f green:235.0f/255.0f blue:213.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
} @daskblinkenlight

Comment: See if you can avoid calling `setViewControllers` repeatedly.